# understanding how imports work in solidity

Tags: solidity

I am a beginner and trying to understand imports, especially in solidity. Say for example I import a contract from github to my smart contract and submit it to the blockchain, I am assuming that even if the github repository changes, the smart contract will stay as it was at the time of import and valid?

Secondly if I have a bunch of files in my local directory and import them into a main contract and then submit the main contract with the imports to the blockchain, will that smart contract work fine on the main net?

Apologies if this is a noob question lol, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when you import a Github contract, it is the same as if you copy/paste that contract into a new file and simply import that file into your main contract. So when you deploy the smart contract think it as if the compiler mixed those contracts with the state they had at the moment of deployment, so any changes made to any of those contracts won't change the deployed code, as smart contracts are nearly immutable.

As regards the second question, it will work fine as long as all the logic is correct.